# H2 in memory , как инициализировать данные?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

Использую H2 in memory + hibernate , нужно при загрузке и выключении загружать и сохранять данные в sql скрипт, как это реализовать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря как используете. Один из вариантов инициализации [описан в документации](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection):

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=runscript from '~/create.sql'\\;runscript from '~/init.sql'";
```